# using sonarcloud for junit analysis fails when the source code version is jdk1.8 but sonarcloud uses jdk17

Tags: java-8, azure-pipelines, compatibility, java-17, sonarcloud

This is the error message getting when the maven verify command is executed from azure pipeline
Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.10.0.2594:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.10.0.2594:sonar: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I am expecting my code should get built and should be successfully analyzed when calling the sonarcloud from the azure pipeline

Comment: have you tried to use other images to run the pipeline or select Java version manually? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

> Java used to run SonarScanner: Java 8 in SonarQube 8.9, Java 11 in SonarQube 9.0 and higher.

You can upgrade your JDK to JDK11 or downgrade SonarQube to 8.9. To use JDK11 in the DevOps pipeline, you can try the suggestions below.

1. Use image `Ubuntu 20.04` or `Ubuntu 22.04` to run your pipeline. The default version of Java JDK is `11.0.21+9`. See the [software in the images](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/tree/ubuntu22/20240116.3/images).
2. Select Java version manually when using maven task. Set`javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'` and `jdkVersionOption: '1.11'`.

```
    - task: Maven@3
      displayName: 'Execute Maven goal'
      inputs:
        mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
        options: '-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true'
        mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
        mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
        javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
        jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
        jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
        publishJUnitResults: true
        mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
        effectivePomSkip: false
        sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
        sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'latest'
        codeCoverageToolOption: 'JaCoCo'
        testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
        goals: 'verify'
```